# Does my double flush valve need replacement

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flushvlave

I have a problem with my double flush valve in the toilet tank. Installed it looks like this:
[image: inside the cistern, showing the flush valve]

Now the problem is, when pushing either of the two buttons, or both together, the water in the tank doesn't release to flush the toilet.I got the centre piece out:

[image: bottom of disassembled flush valve]

I realized that the disk with the grey rubber ring, just falls off the centre piece that lifts up when the buttons are pushed on top. I imagine it should pull up the disk to release the water but it doesn't stick on there, it just pops right off.

I got it somewhat reassembled, but with a little vibration it falls right off, it just holds on there by friction.

[image: reassembled flush valve]

It seems like some thing that holds it up may be missing...? Any hints?
The assembly looks to be the same as this one from WaterMark: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Watermark-Upc-Toilet-Htd-New-Wra_60870640816.html

Comment: Are there any brand/model number markings on the valve? If so, sharing that would go a long way toward allowing someone to look up the instructions to see how it should be assembled and if something is broken/missing. Did you look in the bottom of the tank to see if there were any stray parts hanging out down there?

Comment: It's a WarerMark type of assembly, I've added a link to a model that looks to be the same above

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say yes, replace it. A "T" that the bottom diaphragm clips onto or receives is missing. But, you could try drilling through (aligned with the wide ribbed legs) while assembled and put a screw or piece of a screw (stainless steel) through to hold the diaphragm on.

Comment: Frankly, while a replacement would probably cost more than a cup of coffee, it's probably not worth the time, effort or hassle of trying to bodge a repair if parts are missing or broken.